# adding new line to Qstring after spliting

Tags: c++, json, qt

I have Following Qstring

```
"diskinfo": "Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 420842713088, Name: C:, Size  : 499875049472  Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: , Name: D:, Size  :   Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 324858568704, Name: E:, Size  : 487687450624  Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: 0, Name: F:, Size  : 553459712",
```

I need the following output

```
{
  "diskinfo": "Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 420842713088, Name: C:, Size  : 499875049472
              Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: , Name: D:, Size  : 
              Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: Local Fixed Disk, FreeSpace: 324858568704, Name: E:, Size  : 487687450624 
              Node: ASHUTOSH-PC, Description: CD-ROM Disc, FreeSpace: 0, Name: F:, Size  : 553459712",
}
```

How is this possible ? in  Qt

Following is my code to obtain the Qstring

```
QString WctUtils::getDiskSpace( )
 {
     static QString diskSpaceCmd ( qgetenv("WINDIR")
                               + "\\system32\\wbem\\wmic logicaldisk get name, freespace, size, description /format:csv");

    QProcess proc;
    QByteArray qba;
    QString out_str;


    proc.start(diskSpaceCmd);

    if(proc.waitForFinished(-1))
        {
         qba = proc.readAllStandardOutput();
         qba = qba.trimmed();
         qba =qba.replace('\r',' ');
         QString myString =qba;

         QStringList myStringList = myString.split("\n");

         QStringList descriptions = myStringList[0].split(",");

         for(int index = 1;index < myStringList.length();index++)
           {
              QStringList data = myStringList[index].split(",");
              QStringList out;
              for(int ind_2 = 0; ind_2 < data.length(); ind_2++)
              out.push_back(descriptions[ind_2] + ": " +data[ind_2]);
              out_str += out.join(", ");
           }


     }

      QString diskSpace(out_str);
      return (diskSpace);
 }
```

How is it poosible to append string staring with word'node' in new line in qt c++?

Comment: there is no newline in first string, why do you split with  new line, myString.split("\n") ?

Comment: Before this string I had a string with \n , then i splitted it using \n , and then Got my Qstring as above . Now What i want is whenever node starts It should be appended to new line  in that Qstring How is it possible? Or Do we have o convert it into QJSon array?

Answer (score 0):

I would split on the word "Node:", and then because the split removes what you're splitting on, in the results, preprend the "Node:" back onto each string. You can do that by:

```
for (int index = 1; index < myStringList.length(); index++)
{
    myStringList[index] = "Node:" + myStringList[index];
}
```